# VBA Macro to combine CSV Files with Command Line copy function

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I've written a macro which enables files within a selected folder to be combined using the command shell. The reason I'm using the command prompt is that the files are large and take some time to open.

The problem is that when I pick a folder that contains a space (i.e. J:\Network Accrual\Invoices) the macro fails. I've attempted to follow other suggestions that include 4 quotations ("""" & path & """"), however this does not seem to for the operation I have set - "cmd.exe /C copy  J:\TEST*csv J:\TEST\Combined.csv".

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub COMBINE_FILES()

Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim myPath As String

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Display path
MsgBox myPath

 'Combine files in Command Line
  Dim RET As Variant
  RET = Shell("cmd.exe /C copy  " & myPath & "*csv " & myPath & "Combine.csv", 0)

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RET = Shell("cmd.exe /C copy  """ & myPath & "*csv"" """ & myPath & "Combine.csv""", 0)
```